# Has there been any independent verification of the results from this Chinese nanotube study?

Tags: space-elevator

[Watts up](https://wattsupwiththat.com/2018/10/26/space-race-game-changer-chinese-space-elevator-breakthrough/) referred to the [South China Morning Post](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/society/article/2170193/china-has-strongest-fibre-can-haul-160-elephants-and-space) in reporting that a Tsinghua University team led by Wei Fei claimed in 2018 to have manufactured carbon nanotube fibre has tensile strength of 80 gigapascals.

Has this result been verified or reproduced independently?

Comment: Published July 2018 in Nature Nanotechnology [Carbon nanotube bundles with tensile strength over 80 GPa](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41565-018-0141-z) (available in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325128963_Carbon_nanotube_bundles_with_tensile_strength_over_80_GPa)). I haven't found any independent verification published yet, but that doesn't mean it hasn't been. With venture capital in the back of everybody's mind people are probably working hard on this but not sharing their "secret sauce" until the patents are filed.

Comment: different, but related (and currently unanswered): [Chinese find material to make space elevator. How much will the cable weigh?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31624/12102)

Comment: This is probably a better fit for Chemistry.SE as it has nothing to do with space exploration.

Comment: I reproduced it on Chem.SE. Feel free to close here. Space elevator would be really nice for space exploration, but I can see how the immediate topic doesn't really relate.